# PHP preg_match for only numbers and letters, no special characters

Tags: php

I don't want preg_match_all ... because the form field only allows for numbers and letters... just wondering what the right syntax is...

Nothing fancy ... just need to know the right syntax for a preg_match statement that looks for only numbers and letters. Something like

```
preg_match('/^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.com$/', $unit)
```

But that doesn't look for numbers too....

Comment: Please, be a little more precisely what you'd like to do.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what you're trying to achieve here? Maybe an example. Are you trying to match all alphanum or just the first one, or something else?

Comment: Why don't you want `preg_match_all`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you just want to ensure a string contains only alphanumeric characters. A-Z, a-z, 0-9 you don't need to use regular expressions.

Use [**`ctype_alnum()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

Example from the documentation:

```
<?php
$strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#$bar');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all letters or digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all letters or digits.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
The string AbCd1zyZ9 consists of all letters or digits.
The string foo!#$bar does not consist of all letters or digits.
```

Comment: I did not know about `ctype_alnum`.  +1

Answer (score 16):

```
if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9]+/", $content) == TRUE){

} else {

}
```

Comment: It won't let me edit it because it's not enough characters, but ("/(A-Za-z0-9]+/", $content) should be ("/[A-Za-z0-9]+/", $content). Notice the [ instead of (

Comment: @emilyk tried two times to process an edit to fix this but got denied every time. So we'll stick with the not working version then.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to match more than 1, then you'll need to, however, provide us with some code and we can help better.

although, in the meantime:

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9])/", $formContent, $result);
print_r($result);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Test it :

```
preg_match('/\A[a-z0-9]+\z/i', $myInput);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it