# password checking function with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, validation

i have this function:

```
public static function encPasswordCheckFailed($password)
    {
        if (!preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $password)){
            return true;
        }
        if (!preg_match('/[a-z]+/', $password)){
            return true;
        }
        if (!preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $password)){
            return true;
        }
        if (!preg_match('/[!@#$%^&*()-+<>]+/', $password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and now i want to force the user to have at least 1 Uppercased Letter, 1 Lowercased Letter, 1 Number and 1 Specialcharacter.

I'm having the problem with this:

```
if (!preg_match('/[!@#$%^&*()-+<>]+/', $password)) {
    return true;
}
```

All other requirements work. I have only a problem with the specialcharacters. 

Can someone tell me the correct pattern for these specialcharacters: `!@#$%^&*()-+<>`

**i've read some of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5553397/5930557), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588202/5930557) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937607/5930557) but they didn't help me further...**

Comment: From first sight.. escape the `-`, though it's not that harmful in this case. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544250/php-password-validation?

Comment: look at Doruk Ayar answer. You have to escape (\) special characters for regex to "see" them as characters.

Comment: Just escape the dash `-` or move it at the begining or at the end of the character class.

Comment: still not woking...

Comment: What is not working? What do you get? What are you expecting? Could you show us your test cases?

Comment: `if (!preg_match('/[!@#$%^&*()+<>-]/', $password))` should trigger if a string has no special chars defined in the char class. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/23teqX/2). Since `wxN5n>N1gdtsJyOEGak46hHkNgd4-^` contains some of the special chars, the `!preg_match` will not get triggered.

Comment: the pattern from the answer from below `'/\[!@#$%^&*\(\)-+<>\]+/'` is not working. in my input field i tried to enter a password like: `wxN5n>N1gdtsJyOEGak46hHkNgd4-^` but the functions still returns true. im my case all my errors are handled with true and if it passes the match then it returns false

Comment: Of course, it is wrong! Did you try to escape the dash only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and what is then the correct way to handle it ?

Comment: @Toto i don't understand your question...

Comment: @Blueblazer172: I do not understand *your* question. `if (!preg_match('/[!@#$%^&*()+<>-]/', $password))` should be the right approach. With this, the result for `encPasswordCheckFailed("wxN5n>N1gdtsJyOEGak46hHkNgd4-^")` is *False*, I guess it is expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah thats right

Comment: Escape the dash (ie. `[!@#$%^&*()\-+<>]`) or move it at the begining `[-!@#$%^&*()+<>*]`  or at the end `[!@#$%^&*()+<>*-]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why did you close the question.. the pattern from the anser you linked it is not working. look [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/W73yV7AgDL) for me only [this](http://www.rubular.com/r/25dd349idb) worked

Comment: The answer is: put the `-` to the end/start of the character class as in case it is inside between separate chars it creates a range. Or escape the hyphen.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah ok now i understand :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dash/minus character is your issue, as when inside a character group, it denotes a character range.

You need to either:

- Escape it with a backslash, so that it isn't treated as a special character:
  `/[!@#$%^&*()\-+<>]+/`
- Or put it at the end of the pattern, so the PCRE engine knows it can't possibly denote a range:
  `/[!@#$%^&*()+<>-]+/`

Similarly, the caret (`^`) is also a special character, denoting negation when inside a character group, but because you didn't put it at the very first position inside the character group, the PCRE engine knows it has no special meaning in your case.

Comment: this worked finally:) thanks

Answer (score 2):

> You may need to escape some special characters used by the Regex Engine. And by the way, you could as well do that in one Go as shown below. [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/678743).

```
<?php


    /*public static*/ function encPasswordCheckFailed($password) {
        // THIS READS:
        // IF THE PASSWORD DOES CONTAIN AN UPPER-CASE CHARACTER
        // AND ALSO DOES CONTAIN A LOWER-CASE CHARACTER
        // AND STILL DOES CONTAIN A NUMERIC CHARACTER
        // AND EVEN MORE, DOES CONTAIN ANY  OF THE SPECIFIED SPECIAL CHARACTERS 
        // RETURN FALSE OTHERWISE RETURN TRUE
        if (preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $password) &&                    // CHECK FOR UPPERCASE CHARACTER
            preg_match('/[a-z]+/', $password) &&                    // AND CHECK FOR LOWERCASE CHARACTER
            preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $password)&&                     // AND CHECK FOR NUMERIC CHARACTER
            preg_match('/[\!@#$%\^&\*\(\)\-\+<>]+/', $password)     // AND CHECK FOR SPECIAL CHARACTER
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    var_dump( encPasswordCheckFailed("abcd123") );    //<== boolean true
    var_dump( encPasswordCheckFailed("abcD123") );    //<== boolean true
    var_dump( encPasswordCheckFailed("abcD1@23-") );  //<== boolean false
```

Answer (score 0):

This will gonna work for special characters:

```
preg_match('/\[!@#$%^&*\(\)\-+<>\]+/', $password);
```

> If it's not working, look down:

**OTHER ANSWERS:**

1. [preg_match php special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937569/preg-match-php-special-characters/9643219#9643219) ([pmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919471/pmm)'s answer)

Comment: not working....

Comment: this ruins my whole code...

Comment: the answer from pmm destroys my code...

Comment: if i use your code the function returns true which is in my case an error. and an error message is showing up